# Remove the strikethrough on the edit review page

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design, diff

When going through the edit review, it's hard for me to compare code before and after because of the strikethroughs in the red marked code.

[image: strikethrough on edit review]

It's harder for me to digest/compare the old code to the new code when there is a strikethrough through the low contrast old code text, then when there is no strikethrough.

I do realize that in the edited code relevant replaced blocks are marked with dark green, but sometimes I really need to look at the original code, and the strikethrough hampers my ability to discern accolades {}, dashes, and a couple of other characters. It also slows down my reading because I have to be extra attentive as the normal reading flow is interrupted.

**The feature request**
Please keep the "changed" or removed code red, but remove the strikethrough part. when using a side by side comparison view.

It's already red and on the left. That's marking and difference enough. It's already harder to read because there is barely any contrast in the deleted text and no code highlighting, the strikethrough is an extra obstacle.

The below examples are not per see reviews where I need that extra detail, but just to illustrate the obstacle in reading the strikethrough gives to parsing the text.

With strikethrough:
[image: strikethrough enabled]

Without strikethrough
[image: without strikethrough]

Comment: If you are doing a lot of review custom css or script may be the fastest solution.

Comment: Not saying the current visualization is ideal but relying on the difference in color alone is probably not a good idea either. Some people are color blind.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed good point. But then maybe remove the strikethrough when doing side by side comparison. One can assume the part on the left is the old code. Kinda like a traffic light. The top is red, bottom is green. Modified my feature request. Thanks

Comment: I think perhaps the best option for everyone is having a checkbox that can be checked/unchecked at any time with the result of having/not having the strikethrough.

Comment: Better yet, add a `-` at the start of the line. Helps a bit with accessibility issues for colorblind people, still keeps the text readable